# localStorage onclick add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

The below onclick event is working good. I want the same event should work after we reloading the page also. I tried to implement the localStorage method but not getting the expected output.

Anyone help me resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Script I have tried:

```
$("ul li").click(function () {
    $('ul li').removeClass("one");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    localStorage.setItem('listItem', 'one');
}); 
$(document).ready(function(){   
    if(localStorage.getItem('listItem') == 'one') {                               
        $('ul li').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```js
$('ul li').click(function(){ 
  $("ul li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
ul li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The phrase "not working for me" is a red flag in a question - you need to define what exactly happens, and how it differs from what you expect. Especially in this case when Stack Snippets can't reproduce your problem. For one thing, your click handler could be set before the document is ready, so the `<li>` elements don't actually have it set. For another, reload could colour all the items red, since you don't save in storage which element is selected. Yet another possibility is something else entirely is breaking, since you had to change the structure of the code for the Stack Snippet.

Comment: The update "not getting the expected output" is no better. Please specify how _exactly_ your system behaves, and in which ways _specifically_ it is different from what you want. E.g. "When I click the second `<li>`, it turns red, but when I reload, all the elements show up as thunderclouds instead", "When I click the second `<li>`, my computer explodes, but what I expect is to see the clicked list item to turn red and no explosions whatsoever", or similar.

Comment: @Saravana actually you need , when clicked li active after page reload  right ?

Comment: @ShafeelSha Yes. exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Tested code. or  [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/shafeel_sha/mhsLjbg6/7/) 

Note:  keep li id's are unique

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
         ul li.active {
         color: red;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body >
      <ul>
         <li id="1">One</li>
         <li id="2">Two</li>
         <li id="3">Three</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("ul li").each(function(index) {
   if ($(this).attr('id') == localStorage.getItem("Activeli")) {
     $(this).addClass("active");
   }
   });
   response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlistID"));
   $('a[data-pdtId="' + response + '"]').addClass('active')

   });


   $('ul li').click(function() {
   $("ul li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   console.log(id);
   localStorage.setItem("Activeli", id); //create a localstorage
   });

</script>



Hope this help you, thanks
```

Comment: I have to keep the id for `li`?

Comment: sure , that id identify clicked li

Comment: post your code in snippet here. I can mark as valid.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect solution of your problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul li.active {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="hello">
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('ul li').click(function(){    
        $("ul li").removeClass("active");
        $('ul li').removeAttr('id');
        $(this).addClass("active");


        var activeElement =  $(this).text();
        console.log(activeElement);
        localStorage.setItem('active', activeElement);
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "ul li" ).each(function( index ) {
            if($( this ).text() == localStorage.getItem('active')){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pushpraj13/5hwz78y3/2/) where you can check your output. Note: clear your localStorage before executing the code.

Comment: when I integrate into my website its all become `li.active` after reload the page.

Comment: lemme give you fiddle link , you can test it over there . And clear your local storage before executing  . @Saravana

Comment: I can upvote only. But not getting the desired output.

Comment: What's your desired output ? @Saravana

Comment: see the below @shafeel sha I got solution with that.

Comment: That's what my code was doing . Anyways Thank you so much appreciation by upvoting the answer sir . @Saravana

Comment: You're always welcome. Thank you for time and effort.